# I am trying to read a value from oracle anonymous block using JdbcTemplate

Tags: sql, spring, oracle, spring-boot, jdbctemplate

I am trying to read a value from oracle anonymous block using JdbcTemplate. Here is my java code:

```
getJdbcTemplate().queryForObject(sql, Boolean.class);
```

And here is the sql:

```
DECLARE
    CRS                SYS_REFCURSOR;

BEGIN

    OPEN CRS FOR SELECT CASE
                            WHEN
                                      1 > 0
                                THEN 1
                            ELSE 0
                            END
                 FROM DUAL;
END;
```

I am receiving this error:

```
 SQL state [99999]; error code [17166]; Cannot perform fetch on a PLSQL statement: next; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Cannot perform fetch on a PLSQL statement: next
```

Comment: You open a cursor but you do not do anything with it and you have not used any bind variables in the anonymous block. Why not simply try something like `DECLARE i PLS_INTEGER := 0; BEGIN ? := i; END;` (or, even more simply, `BEGIN ? := 0; END;`) and then get the bind value into an out parameter in JDBC?

Comment: But then I assume I'd need an output parameter with `JdbcTemplate`, so the `getJdbcTemplate().queryForObject(sql, Boolean.class);` changes because then Spring fails with `given 1 parameters but expected 0.` Is there a way to get it without using an output parameter? @MT0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`public <T> T queryForObject(String sql, Class<T> requiredType) throws DataAccessException` takes an SQL query that will generate a result set with a single row and constructs an object of the required type using that row from the returned result set.

The code:

```sql
DECLARE
  CRS SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
  OPEN CRS FOR
    SELECT CASE WHEN 1 > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END FROM DUAL;
END;
```

Opens a cursor that would contain a result set with a single row; however, the cursor is held as a local variable within the PL/SQL anonymous block and is never "returned" to the application code that calls the PL/SQL.

The traditional way would be to use SQL without the PL/SQL wrapper:

```java
String sql = "SELECT CASE WHEN 1 > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END FROM DUAL";
getJdbcTemplate().queryForObject(sql, Boolean.class);
```

You could try using `DBMS_SQL.RETURN_RESULT` from the PL/SQL block but that is only available from Oracle 12 and it does not have the same level of support that traditional SQL queries do so it may not work:

```sql
DECLARE
  crs SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
  OPEN crs FOR
    SELECT CASE WHEN 1 > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END FROM DUAL;
  DBMS_SQL.RETURN_RESULT(crs);
END;
```